# Deciphering unknown site organization with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

So I am trying to take any website restaurante menu, and grab it and then based on an algorithm I already have, do something with it. Here is my issue:

**These menus are always in different formats!**

Example: One menu may have different classes for things like price and name and description, while another could use  for name and

for both price and description. Some other menus even have extra information on the top of their page.

My point is that the organization of each menu and the way the information is displayed varies on the website.

If I have the website for the menu, it is easy to grab the code, but parsing through it and organizing the information from it in the same way for each restaurante is something I have not been able to figure out.

So this question goes for more than just this example...If you have a function that takes a url and grabs the code and needs to organize it a certain way, what are the possible methods for writing a code that will be able to work in many different formats?

Note: Yes, the codes can be different, but they will not vary greatly. There will always be a price, a name, and a description, and they will all most likely be put into categories. So I know this is possible in this case, I just have no clue how to even get started...any ideas?

**What I am trying to do in the code:**

I want to basically create a dictionary as such:

```
{food_kind1:['name1/description1/price1','name2/description2,price2'],
 food_kind2:['name1/description1/price1','name2/description2,price2']}
```

The food_kindX will be the big headers for the different kinds of food on the menu like meat, fish, etc.

Doing what I want isn't hard, it's just being able to always read the document no matter the format. So help please! Let me know if I am not being clear

**Menu examples**

1:

```
<h2>Burgers</h2>
<div>
<header>
<h3>California</h3>
</header>
<p>sharp cheddar | hass avocado | watercress | tomatoes | raw red onions<br />
salsa verde <small><span style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 19px;">11.95$</span></small></p>
</div>
```

2:

```
<h4>ANTIPASTI</h4>
<ul>
    <span class="menuitem">Calamari Fritti</span>
    <span class="menuprice"> - $11.95</span>
    <span class="menudescription">Delicate tender calamari rings pan-fried until golden crisp. Topped with hot cherry peppers and served with our house made cocktail sauce and lemon garnish. </span>
    <br /><br />
    <span class="menuitem">Vongole Casino</span>
    <span class="menuprice"> - $10.95</span><br/>
    <span class="menudescription">Shucked littleneck clams topped with roasted red pepper, bacon and bread crumbs, then baked. </span>
</ul>
```

The First one has:

- it's food_kindX in an `<h2>` tag
- each entry would be in a `<div>` tag
- the name is in a `<header>` tag
- the description with the price in a `<p>` tag with the price in a
  `<small>` tag

The second one has:

- it's food_kindX in an `<h4>` tag
- each entry is separated by two `</br>` tags
- the name is in the `menuitem` class
- the description is in the `menudescription` class
- the price is in the `menuprice` class

So as you can see, they are somewhat similar in that they have the same information and organized in a similar way, but the first mainly uses different tags, while the second uses mainly classes. Menus really vary and I need to be able to always determine the categories, and each meal with it's name, description, and price.

Comment: If you could post the _html_ of different formatted menus, may be it would be a bit easier to help

Comment: I added two examples that vary with a detailed explanation. Hopefully that is helpful

Answer (score 1):

Consider using regular expressions to interpret the the two types of menus.

Here's how to scrape the first menu example:

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict

menu_dict = defaultdict(list)

pattern = '<h2>(.*?)</h2>.*?<div>.*?<h3>(.*?)</h3>.*?<p>(.*?)<small><span .*?>(.*?)</span>'
text    = '''<h2>Burgers</h2>
                 <div>
                 <header>
                     <h3>California</h3>
                 </header>
             <p>sharp cheddar | hass avocado | watercress | tomatoes | raw red onions<br />
             salsa verde <small><span style="font-size: 13px; line-height: 19px;">11.95$</span></small></p></div>'''

results = re.findall(pattern, text, re.DOTALL)

for r in results:
    kind = r[0]
    name = r[1]
    description = r[2].replace('<br />\n', ' | ')
    price = r[3]

    value = name + '/' + description + '/' + price
    menu_dict[kind].append(value)
```

Here's a similar example for the second menu:

```
import re

pattern = '<span class="menuitem">(.*?)</span>.*?<span class="menuprice">(.*?)</span>.*?<span class="menudescription">(.*?)</span>'

text    = '''<h4>ANTIPASTI</h4>
                 <ul>
                     <span class="menuitem">Calamari Fritti</span>
                     <span class="menuprice"> - $11.95</span>
                     <span class="menudescription">Delicate tender calamari rings pan-fried until golden crisp. Topped with hot cherry peppers and served with our house made cocktail sauce and lemon garnish. </span>
                     <br /><br />
                     <span class="menuitem">Vongole Casino</span>
                     <span class="menuprice"> - $10.95</span><br/>
                     <span class="menudescription">Shucked littleneck clams topped with roasted red pepper, bacon and bread crumbs, then baked. </span>
                 </ul>'''

results = re.findall(pattern, text, re.DOTALL)

for r in results:
    name = r[0]
    price = r[1][3:]
    description = r[2]
```

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: +1 for the fact that you showed me how I can do it...but the problem was not solved. My issue is that I wont know the pattern before hand. The only thing that I can think of is to write a function that takes an html doc, and figures out the section the menu is in, and then figures out the pattern. Then I could put the pattern into what you have shown, and it would always work. So is the function I need to figure out this pattern possible? I don't need a concrete answer of how if you can't, but maybe an explanation of what I could use and what would be useful for that function. Make sense?

Comment: The findall() method finds all instances of the foods that match the pattern. So you don't really need to find out which section you're in. If you're in the wrong section, the regular expression won't match and you'll be safe. Hope this helps!

Comment: but I don't know what the pattern is, it can be anything, so this wont be able to pick up anything unless I already know the pattern

Comment: I thought the question was that you had these two types of patterns which you wanted to identify. If the pattern is "anything", then you're probably best off compiling your data by hand.

Comment: No haha, somebody requested examples...but no worries, there is an API I found after digging and digging and digging that does this for me!! it's called Locu